# "ухудшение прав и гарантий"

Tags: семантика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли сказать: "ухудшение прав и гарантий", и, если нет, то как сказать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Корректное выражение: **ограничение/расширение прав и гарантий.**

Кроме того,  права и гарантии **обеспечивают, иногда укрепляют**, например: Большое количество жалоб указывает на серьезные проблемы с **обеспечением прав и гарантий** этой категории граждан. Вместе с **укреплением прав и гарантий** свободной личности укрепляются права и гарантии свободной национальности.

**Ухудшение прав - неудачное сочетание, и вот пример на эту тему:** Все, что улучшает положение работников по сравнению с законодательством, может быть закреплено в трудовых договорах, **ухудшение** (= ограничение) **прав и гарантий** работника недопустимо. [Михаил Михайловский. Новый кодекс // «Отечественные записки», 2003].

Comment: Боюсь, что здесь не ограничение самих прав имеется в виду, а их реализация. Скажем, рост бюрократические барьеров

Answer (score 0):

Права и гарантии - вещь закрепленная и не имеющая критерия "плохой-хороший". Они всегда имеют положительную коннотацию (если, конечно, не в устах чеховского унтера Пришибеева). Поэтому сами они не должны не должны улучшаться или, там, улучшаться.
Могут изменяться, появляться, исчезать, урезаться (минимизироваться), наконец. ***Ухудшаться*** может ***положение*** с правами, ***ситуация*** в области права, ***защита*** прав. Выбирайте по ситуации.

Comment: То есть "у этого страховщика плохие гарантии" - нонсенс?)

Comment: @Aer Да, это нонсенс, но не по грамматическим соображениям ))) С грамматикой тут в обще-то все более или менее, хотя и отдает профжаргоном. Но я, во-первых, отвечал более по части "прав", а во-вторых, "ухудшения". А конкретно по страховщику с "плохими гарантиями" мне не совсем понятно, что под этой ситуацией понимать. Страховщик не заслуживает доверия? Или его гарантии не покрывают в достаточной мере возможные риски? Вот тут-то и призадумаешься о том, как иначе эту мысль выразить.

Comment: @Aer Гарантии не могут быть плохими или хорошими: они могут быть обеспеченными и необеспеченными (деньгами, валютой, другими активами). Также, страховщик при наступлении страхового случая гарантирует возмещение ущерба, но возмещает не полностью сумму ущерба, а лишь малую долю. И (в сравнении с другим страховщиком) его условия возмещения могут быть намного хуже.

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска ответа на вопрос стоит обратиться к словарям:

Право:

> 1. (ед.) Совокупность устанавливаемых и охраняемых государственной властью норм и правил, регулирующих отношения людей в обществе, а также наука, изучающая эти нормы. Может ли это *ухудшиться* (стать плохим)? Навряд ли.
> 2. Охраняемая государством, узаконенная возможность что-н. делать, осуществлять. Может ли это *ухудшиться*? Нет.
> 3. Возможность действовать, поступать каким-н. образом. Может? Нет.
> 4. Основание, причина. Может? Нет.
> 5. (мн.) Автомобильные права (я сократил). Могут ли они стать плохими? Чушь.

Следовательно, право ухудшиться **не может**, а значит, **словосочетание** уже **неверно**.

Гарантия:

> 1. Условие, обеспечивающее успех, осуществление чего-либо. Может ли это стать плохим? В принципе, да: представим ситуацию, когда женщина, уже пользовавшаяся услугами страховой фирмы, стала недовольна новыми условиями и говорит подруге, что у ООО "Страханет" *ухудшились гарантии* (то есть компания уже не может, по мнению женщины1, обеспечить успех чего-либо).
> 2. (юр.) Обещание кого-либо принять на себя компенсацию убытков в случае невыполнения кем-либо своих обязательств. Может ли? Нет.
> 3. (мн.) То же, что залог; то, что может являться компенсацией в случае невыполнения кем-либо своих обязательств. Может ли компенсация стать плохой? Да.
> 4. (разг.) То же, что гарантийный срок. Может? Да.

Таким образом, в некоторых ситуациях говорить об ухудшении гарантии (-ий) **можно**.

Чтобы дать совет, как сказать правильно, нужно понять, что вы хотите сказать. Будьте добры, объясните мысль.

Comment: Поясняю подробнее: в проекте коллективного договора текст выглядит следующим образом: "не могут содержать условий, снижающих уровень прав и гарантий работников". Юрист настоятельно рекомендует изменить это на "...условий, ухудшающих права и гарантии работников". Я понимаю, что по правилам русского языка это неверно, но мне нужно аргументированно это донести до юриста, который, видимо, недостаточно хорошо зная русский язык, все-таки настаивает на своем варианте.